# imageview source in the java file and the xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Looking at the code below;

```
ImageView theImageView = (ImageView) theView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

theImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
```

Is the second line necessary if we established the source (android:src) of the image in the xml file? XML shown below;

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You either do it in XML or in Java code. You don't have to do it twice.

If you have already define ImageView and set image, then you don't even have to get it's reference in Java code (1st line), unless you want to change something.

Comment: They did this in a tutorial I was watching and it seemed redundant. Thanks for the confirmation.